# curl command is unable to upload files with unicode characters

Tags: batch, curl

I'm trying to upload a file to a FTP site but it looks like when the file name has unicode characters curl is unable to upload it.

```
curl -u %username%:%password% -T "LENOVO - São Paulo.txt" ftp://ftp.drivehq.com/Maquinas/
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
curl: Can't open 'LENOVO - SÃ£o Paulo.txt'!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
```

When the file doesn't have unicode characters all is ok. Any solution to this?

Comment: This sounds like Windows. Are you using the curl.exe that came with Windows, or one downloaded separately, or the one from Cygwin?

Comment: Downloaded separately I'm on Windows 8.1 it doesn't ship with curl by default...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading a new curl version 7.80 it was able to upload the file with unicode characters. I had version 7.76...